# YII2 pagination error in custom code

Tags: php, pagination, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have been trying to apply pagination but getting error.

**In Controller :**

```
public function actionProperties()
    {
        $query= Property::find()->all();
        $countQuery = clone $query;
        $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count()]);
        $propertylist = $query->offset($pages->offset)->limit($pages->limit)->all();
        return $this->render('properties',[ 
            'propertylist' => $propertylist,
            'pages' => $pages,
            ]);
    }
```

**In View :**

```
<?= LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pages,]);?>
```

But getting the following error. Please help...

```
__clone method called on non-object
```

Comment: Are you sure $query returns at least one row from db table?

Comment: Why don't use find()->count()?

Answer (score 0):

The [all() method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#all()-detail) returns an `array` (of objects) not an `object`. And, as you can see by the error, you must use `__clone method` on a `object`.

Can i ask why do you need this `clone` anyway?